# Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000010 (code=1), thread 9967 in samsung galaxy tab 4 7'inch tablet android

Tags: android, encryption, android-service, fatal-error

In my application, we are showing list of some records which are coming from web services. which are encrypted so we are doing decryption using cipher. now, we have also download option for particular record which is service. while downloading, user can also get into that record. we are storing all the records in sqlite and then showing into list or in other controls. we have other service also which is running in background continously for checking any updates.

So now, when I put any record in download and while downloading, moving into any other or same record, some times I get this error on in samsung galaxy tab 4  7 inch tablet. I didnt get any other crash log. only this single line. I dont know what is the reason for this. please help me to solve this problem. I am facing this issue from last one week and still didnt get any solution for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. it was happening due to cursors of database which were open. because of that memory issues occur and application got crashed. so i just close every cursor in my whole app and now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Logcat to check for errors that can lead to this fatal error. Also it is possible that your tablet has hardware of software errors - try launching app on another device of the same model.

Comment: I already mention that I didnt get any other error logs. only this single line which I mention in question title.

Comment: So, you already tried debugging with logcat? In that case it can be hardware\software problem with device. You can only add some debug info to locate error source and try refactoring it.

Comment: debug info.?? I dont understand. can you help me.?

Comment: Just add `Log.d("I am doing something")` in many places to try locating when error is triggered.

Comment: It triggered when service response come. but it happens sometimes. not everytime.

Comment: Signal 11 is segmentation fault. This means the program is trying to access memory it doesn't have permission for. It can happen for many different reasons so I am afraid I can't help you to locate this bug. I can only advice testing on different devices and updating app's dependencies.

Comment: check /data/tombstones directory for logs related to segmentation faults. There is a new file created under this folder for each fault.